# Matplotlib bar plot autolabel subplots - name 'axs' isn't recognized

Tags: python, matplotlib

I define a function to automatically create three bar plots one above the other (so with subplots) from one single dataframe and inside this function I call another function to label each bar.

Here is the bar plot function (really simplified but the problem is a priori the same):

```
> def bar_plot_one_category_by_year(df_name,category,df_years=['2019','2020']):
>     nbr_of_years=len(df_years)
>     sorts_of_representation_list=['number','sum','median']
>     
>     # Dataframes list
>     df_list=[]
>     for i in range(nbr_of_years):
>         df_list=df_list.append(globals()[df_name+df_years])
>     
>     # Create a figure with subplots
>     fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1,figsize=(18,18))
>     
>     # Bars setup
>     bar_width=0.4
>     bar_width_shift_factor=1.1
>     bar_shift=bar_width*bar_width_shift_factor # Shift values of bars from the center of ticks
>     bar_shift_list=[bar_shift*i for i in [i-nbr_of_years/2 for i in range(nbr_of_years)]]
>     colors=['r','b']
>     
>     # xticks
>     nbr_of_xticks=len(df_list[0])
>     xticks_pos=np.arange(nbr_of_xticks) # ticks position
>     if nbr_of_years%2==0:
>         plt.setp(axs, xticks=xticks_pos-bar_shift/2)
>     else:
>         plt.setp(axs, xticks=xticks_pos)
>     
>     # Plot 1 - by number
>     list_number = []
>     for i in range(0,nbr_of_years):
>         list_number.append(list(df_list[i]['Number']))
>         plot_number=axs[0].bar(xticks_pos + bar_shift_list[i], height = list_number[i], width = bar_width, color = colors[i], align='center', label=df_years[i])
>         autolabel(plot_number,axs_nbr=0)
>     axs[0].set_title('Number',fontdict=fontdict)
>     axs[0].legend()
> 
>     # Plot 2 - by sum
>     list_sum = []
>     for i in range(0,nbr_of_years):
>         list_sum.append(list(df_list[i]['Total_paid_amount']))
>         plot_sum=axs[1].bar(xticks_pos + bar_shift_list[i], height = list_sum[i], width = bar_width, color = colors[i], align='center',
> label=df_years[i])
>         autolabel(plot_sum,axs_nbr=1)
>     axs[1].set_title('Total paid amount')
>     axs[1].legend()
> 
>     # Plot 3 - by median
>     list_median = []
>     for i in range(0,nbr_of_years):
>         list_median.append(list(df_list[i]['Median_of_paid_amounts']))
>         plot_median=axs[2].bar(xticks_pos + bar_shift_list[i], height = list_median[i], color = colors[i],align='center', label=df_years[i])
>         autolabel(plot_median,axs_nbr=2)
>     axs[2].set_title('Median of paid amounts')
>     axs[2].legend()
```

And here is the autolabel function :

```
>     def autolabel(plot_name,fontsize = 8,axs_nbr=0):
>         for p in plot_name.patches:
>             height = p.get_height()
>             if (height != 0):             # Without this condition, we could have a Value message error
>                 axs[axs_nbr].text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., height,'{:,}'.format(int(height)).replace(',',' '),ha='center',
> va='bottom')
```

Problem : I get the error `"NameError: name 'axs' is not defined"`. This error comes after having (hopefully) resolved other problems like "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2" concerning the last plot. It's been hours and I still don't manage to print my labels.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it suffices that I post the question that the answer comes into my head :

add `globals()['axs'] = axs` just below the fig,axs declaration. :)

Comment: rather than using `globals` (which is generally frowned upon), you could pass `axs` into the `autolabel` function as an argument